# How to keep code active in a loop that needs a break in a loop of other code

Tags: python

I have a code called `Trigger.py` that works in looping by making a call to another code called `Pausar_Looping.py`:

```
from time import sleep
import schedule
import datetime
import Pausar_Looping

Pausar_Looping.main()
print("-----------------",datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'),"-----------------")

def trigger():
    Pausar_Looping.main()
    print("-----------------",datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'),"-----------------")

schedule.every(30).seconds.do(trigger)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    sleep(1)
```

The `Pausar_Looping.py` code has a chain of events also in looping where it needs a pause to avoid repeating the second part of the code several times, I called this second part to `print('Continue')`:

```
from random import randrange
import os
import signal
import sys
import time

def kill_terminal():
    os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)

def one():
    number = randrange(3)
    1/number
    return number

def main(sleep_time=0):
    try:
        one()
        if (one() == 2):
            kill_terminal()
    except:
        while True:
            print('Error ONE')
            sleep_time += 1
            print('Next attempt in: '+ str(sleep_time) + ' second(s)')
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            main(sleep_time=sleep_time)
            sys.exit(1)

    print('Continue')
```

> This division of the number 1 by the number zero is just a
> demonstration of the code, because the real code makes a call to a
> JSON request that can give an error if it exceeds the 5 second call
> timeout.

Therefore, when there is an error in `one()`, it must return to the beginning of `main()` and try again as many times as necessary, passing to `print('Continue')` only when everything is correct. So on each call, regardless of how many errors there are, `print('Continue')` can only appear once.

This works perfectly, but as to make this break so I don't go to the second part of the code, I used `sys.exit(1)`, here comes the problem:

The `sys.exit(1)` ends up disabling the looping of the `Trigger.py` code, causing the terminal ends the work after going through `print('Continue')`. I wanted it to keep making calls to `Pausar_Looping.py` every 30 seconds whenever everything went right.

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: `sys.exit(1)` is doing its job, i.e. killing the process. If you only want to stop the function running the loop simply do `return`

Comment: Hi @matszwecja With ```return``` it doesn't work because the ```print('Continue')``` appears more than once

Comment: @matszwecja And to demonstrate that when in error it does not let it pass to the second part, the ```print('Continue')``` cannot appear more than once per call

Comment: Where did you put the return?

Comment: Hi @matszwecja i change ```sys.exit(1)``` to ```return```

Comment: Works just fine for me after just changing `sys.exit` to `return`. You must have some unneeded call to `main()` somewhere in your code. You might want to refactor to remove either infinite loops or recursive calls, that way your code will be much easier to follow.

Comment: @matszwecja I made a simplified version and actually the ```return()``` is working, there must be something in my original code that is duplicating the ```main()``` call really, sorry I said it didn't work! If you can, create an answer so I can mark it as a solution and close the question, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.exit(1)` will do exactly that, kill the process running the Python. If you want to stop just the function that is in an infinite loop, `return` will work just fine.